# How to debug date picker that doesn't render properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, rendering, vuetify.js

I had this vuetify date-picker but then I changed my project to a pre-made template (https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vuetify-material-dashboard)
This template uses vuetify as a framework, but even though everything is working as it should, all my date pickers are bugged. They work as they should, but its style is completely weird as you can see here :

[image]

Any tip on how to understand what's going on?

```
                <v-dialog ref="dialog" v-model="modal" :return-value.sync="date" persistent lazy full-width width="290px">
                  <v-text-field slot="activator" v-model="date" label="Picker in dialog" prepend-icon="event" readonly></v-text-field>
                  <v-date-picker v-model="date" scrollable>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="modal = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                    <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
                  </v-date-picker>
                </v-dialog>

                export default {
                  data() {
                    return {
                    date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
                    modal: false
                    }
                   }
                 }
```

Comment: Hello Nuno. Can you provide some more live code (on codesandbox or something) ?

Comment: Are you sure you need `v-dialog` ? Maybe it will look better wihout a dialog ?

Comment: The code works properly in any live code platform, it got to be something related with the template I adopted. 
About the v-dialog, I'm using the date-picker dialog from the vuetify documentation, as you can see here. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers

Comment: Yes, but you can do it without any v-dialog - like here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-formatting-date - I think it's worth to check it - may be it's about combination of these 3: adopted pre-made template + v-dialog + date-picker

Comment: Well I tried just now some other ways and I they render just the same way. Guess it's not that.

Comment: You can inspect it using dev-tools and see what overrides styles. Maybe this will help.